# Why Spring configuration bean become to another bean whose class name ends with $$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've defined a spring bean configuration class in my spring-boot project like this:

```
@Configuration
public class GgjSsoPropsConfig {}
```

But after the spring-boot application has started, I try to eval this configuration bean's class name, then I got:

```
// System.out.print(this.getClass().getSimpleName())
GgjSsoPropsConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$788ad0f1
```

It seems like my bean has become to a another "proxy bean" ?
By the way, I never enable any `AOP` feature in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Spring AOP uses CGLIB (like in this case) or dynamic proxy to create and add bean instances to application context.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch08s06.html

Comment: Thks for your answer, but I never enable any AOP feature in my project, so it can't be the proxied object generated by AOP utils

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, and I found the answer in this bean post process method:
   `org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor#enhanceConfigurationClasses`

Here is the official comment for this method:

> Post-processes a BeanFactory in search of Configuration class BeanDefinitions;
>   any candidates are then enhanced by a {@link ConfigurationClassEnhancer}.

In fact this new generated enhancer bean is just the subclass of my original configuration class `GgjSsoPropsConfig`, and it inherits parent class's all methods and fields, and added some extra enhancer features by Spring.